# LibGDX: How can I make an animation to my Tiled Map?

Tags: android, animation, libgdx, 2d, android-animation

In my game the player is running away from enemies and when he can't keep up the speed anymore I want the enemies to fade in from the side of the screen as the player is still running as show in this GIF:

http://makeagif.com/Eo4y3d

! Remember that the gamecam is also moving on a Tiled Map Editor map when the enemy is coming.

I'm new to libGDX, so I don't know where I should start and so on. All help I get is appreciated!

Comment: It's very unclear to me what your asking. You can fade sprites by setting the 4th value of `Color`. Sprites have there own otherwise use it on `spriteBatch.setColor(1, 1, 1, .5f)` (50% faded). Other then that LibGDX supplies a `Animation` class that takes a sequence of images to create a animation. Please clarrify your exact needs and what you have tried please.

Comment: Do you want enemy to slide from left and eat your player or something? Just generate an enemy with a speed of more than your player?

Comment: Exactly! I have now implemented a dublicate which spawns on the same place as the player and then I have applied a higher speed so he will after a while catch up. But this is a not a great solution in my eyes. I want the enemy to slide in at a specific time to the shown gamescreen and not need to travel from spawn to where the player is located. With my solution, the enemy needs more speed if the player has ran far away and that's not optimal.